# React Template Literals don't work on SVG?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, use-effect, use-state

I have rendered an svg and morphed it using mouse position in vanilla javascript.
Here is an example(make sure to refresh the page since it doesnt start automatically for some reason): https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-shape-change-mouse-position-sjl0z
In vanilla js I did the following:

```
path.setAttribute("d", `M82 ${coords.y}L0 0H123V170H0L82 ${coords.y}Z`)
```

**The problem:**
I can't implement the same logic in **React**. Whenever I add the template literals
to the svg path it wont accept it.
**Here is my code**: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-svg-shape-morph-mouse-position-r7mx9?file=/src/App.js

This react code gives me an error:

```
  let shape = useRef(null);
  console.log("thiss: " + shape.current);
  shape.current.setAttribute("d", `M82 ${y}L0 0H123V170H0L82 ${y}Z`);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100% 100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <path ref={shape} d="M82 88L0 0H123V170H0L82 88Z" fill="lightblue" />
        {/* <path d="M82 88L0 0H123V170H0L82 ${y}Z" fill="#F9B300" /> */}
      </svg>

      <h1>{`x: ${x}; y: ${y};`}</h1>
    </div>
  );
```

How can I link the mouse position to the svg path shape?
(ps. edited the question to include code snipets)

Comment: Please [edit] the question with the necessary code so your question doesn't rely on external resources. Its nice to have sandboxes but the question should have the minimum amount of code in case the links rot.

Comment: Backticks for template literals ``d={`M82 88L0 0H123V170H0L82 ${y}Z`}``.

Comment: I added some code snipets. @sallf that is how I currently have it, although I get the error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')"

Comment: you can't use percentages as values of the viewBox. **This is wrong: `viewBox="0 0 100% 100%" `**

Comment: Changed it to ```viewBox="0 0 100 100"``` although I still get an error. What is weird is that it works the first time, but after a page refresh it gives me the error.

Comment: @habs you don't need `setAttributes` or to use a ref. Uncomment out the commented `path` and delete the one about it, and change that to use the template literal I wrote above. It should work.

Comment: @sallf ah ok! it looks much cleaner with your suggestion. Although there is now a scaling issue. The svg seems to scale out of its container. How can I restrain it? Currently have: ```<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                        <path width="100%" height="100%" d={`M82 ${y}L0 0H123V170H0L82 ${y}Z`} fill="#F9B300" />```

Comment: It should be scaling to the width of `.App`. If you can't figure it out, consider opening a new question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as we're diverging from your original question, which makes it less helpful to future coders.